# Redistribute sprites in a container when its size change

Tags: c#, wpf, transform, frameworkelement

I have a problem in WPF. I want to redistribute small sprites in a container in response to changes in its size.

If I apply Render or Layout transform to the container, the shape of the sprites is transformed along with their positions (for example, circles become ellipses, lines get thicker/thinner).

Is there a way to automatically redistribute the sprites in any other way than iterating through all children of the container and updating their positions?

(I have A, and want to go to C in response to container size change. Can get B using transforms.)

[image]

Comment: This requires a 9-square image and cannot be done using standard WPF frameworks.

Comment: What is 9-square image? 
Repositioning can always be done. I'm just asking for any built-in automatic action akin to applying transformations.

Comment: If by 9-square image you mean a grid with 9 cells and sprites positioned in them with centre alignment then yes, it's possible but it's not what I want to use. This is ok for few sprites only.

Comment: I can imagine such algorithm only under assumption that we have rectangular region and convenient relative coordinates (relative borders). Then just keep either proportions or absolute distances to bordeers constant.

Comment: What I really wanted to know is if there is any internal/native/already done implementation of "iterate through collection of container's children and change their position to maintain mutual relations intact". It seems there is none. There are no special coordinates needed, and no special assumptions are necessary as every GUI element is roughly rectangular and it's size is usually defined by width/height pair.

Comment: The thing is. Native implementation of ScaleTransform applied as render/layout transform seems to be faster that just iterating through lets say 1000 children and changing their positions. Problem with render transform is that it will change the appearance of the children.

Comment: Ok, as for now I couldn't find any other solution than going through all the children and doing an update. I have only one speed-up idea for interactive manipulation: use viewbox during manipulation and real child reposition upon manipulation finish.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here? Are the graphics shown examples or is this what you actually want your control to display? I'm not sure what problem you are actually trying to solve. You ask if there is a native way of doing this sort of layout and the answer is yes; use layout panels.

Comment: I want the elements added to a container to be repositioned in response to change in size of the container. As in the picture above. I have situation A, container got wider and I want to get C - somehow 'automatically'. C means that the positions of children of the container are maintained in the same relation to the container. 
If the left circle was at x=0.05 in 200pix wide container, it should stay at x=0.05 in 600pix container also. Which means pix position has to change. As far as I know there is no layout panel for that. I just iterate through children and reposition them.